# Chrome extension to access source code of any website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd like to write an extension that will display a popup with a text box, where you enter a word, then the number of occurrences of this word on the current page's source code is displayed. How would I access the current page's source code? Do I have to add a permission in the manifest?

Comment: What's wrong with View Page Source > Ctrl+F?

Comment: Good question, unfortunately nobody knows a solution...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't. You can access the page's DOM source:

```
document.body.InnerHTML
document.head.InnerHTML
```

Though this is different from page source, because it contains results of JavaScript.

If you want to get the page source, you can just fire a XMLHTTPRequest at the page and search the results.

To get the current tab's URL you need the `"tabs"` permission. To download pages in the background page you need the `"http://*/*"` and (if you like) `"https://*/*"` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

HERE!  I'm actually working on something kind of similar.
Source: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", window.location, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);

      }
   }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This is not a real solutions as it sends the request another time which is not the intended behaviour